# JPA query return empty result set for equals condition on a date type field

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm tryng to make a query on a date type field on MySql db.

I use predicate to generate more complex query.

```
Path<Date> path = root.get(attribute);
predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(path, operator.getValue());
```

where attribute is

```
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Expiry, Date> dateInsert;
```

operator.getValue() is

```
binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [Tue Feb 02 00:00:00 CET 2021]
```

Query return empty result set. I use repository for query.

```
expiryRepository.findAll(specification,getPageable(currentIndex))
```

I read a lot of topics about this issue but, no suggested solution works in my case.

Is there possible solution in 2021?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, in my specific case, was caused by different setting of time zone between application and connection. The connection was established with UTC timezone but application works with CET time zone. When in application I  did seted the date at 02 Febbruary 2021 at the 00:00 time, the connection changed it in 01 Febbruary 2021 at 11:00 pm time.

I removed this

```
&serverTimezone=UTC
```

from connection string, and all works fine.